# How to change font of selected and unselected tab intablayout?

Tags: android

how to change `font` of selected and unselected tab using `TabLayout` android `support desing library`?

Answer (score 0):

use this method to change text font of tablayout

```
 private void changeTabsFont() {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView)    tabViewChild).setTypeface(Font.getInstance().getTypeFace(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```